# Knockout.js version 3.4.0 breaks jQuery Chosen plugin binding

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I work in Durandal project, which means I use knockout library. Additionaly, I used the jQuery chosen plugin.

Recently, I upgrade knockout from version 2.0 to version 3.4.0. As side effect, the chosen-plugin got defect. It has a bug: the first selection is always the first item at list, regardless of the real value bound by the ko observable.

Here is a repro:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
  init: function (element) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.options.init(element);          
    $(element).chosen({ disable_search_threshold: 10 });
  },
  update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
    $(element).trigger('chosen:updated');
  }
};

ko.applyBindings({ 
  getItemAvailableAccessTypes: function(data) {
    return [
      {codeForChosen: "Open", AccessTypeName: "Open access"},
      {codeForChosen: "Restricted", AccessTypeName: "No access"}
    ];
  },
 child: {
    AccessType: ko.observable("Restricted")
  }
});
```

```css
.chosen-container { width: 100% !important; }
pre { background: white; padding: 10px; color: #333; font: 11px consolas; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.5.1/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.5.1/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: child">
<select data-bind="chosen: $parent.getItemAvailableAccessTypes($data), value: $data.AccessType,  optionsText: 'AccessTypeName',  optionsValue: 'codeForChosen'"></select>
</div>
<hr>Debug info: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: I can [reproduce the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/99zvjm4u/) I think. (PS. It helps if you add such a repro to the question, makes it easier for others to answer.)

Comment: Vote up, - Thank you for the attached jsFiddle, I added referance to this at the question bode.

Comment: Feel free to inline the code, possibly even as a Stack Snippet (one of the editor toolbar items). Then, if the jsfiddle link ever rots, the question will remain useful to future visitors.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Can you edit my question? Thanks.

Comment: If you hit 'edit' now, or check the question history, you can see how I edited in the repro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the jQuery.chosen plugin, but I might have a fix.

I figured the `<select>` element has two ways of showing its value:

1. It's in the `value` attribute on the select element itself,
2. And there can be an `option` binding with a `selected` attribute (often indicating the initial selection).

I noticed knockout doesn't set the `selected` attribute. When I tried if the plugin was able to correctly set the initial selection with `selected` present, it turned out it was.

Now, the challenge was to include the `selected` attribute in the initially selected option. I thought the `init` method would be the best place for this, but it turns out the default binding doesn't create the option elements until `update`... [It even deletes any elements that are already there](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/options.js#L7).

So, eventually, I put the logic in the `update` binding and everything seems to work as intended.

Please not that you might want to do some further testing. Also, I believe you need to return the original binding's return value since this lets knockout know the descendant bindings are taken care of. Also, you might want to check out the [custom disposal logic](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-disposal.html) to make sure your jQuery widget gets destroyed once the select is removed from the DOM.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
  init: function(element) {
    var optionsReturnValue = ko.bindingHandlers.options.init(element);

    $(element).chosen({
      disable_search_threshold: 10
    });

    return optionsReturnValue;
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);

    var currentValue = ko.unwrap(allBindings.get("value"));
    var selectedOption = element.querySelector("[value=" + currentValue + "]");
    if (selectedOption) {
      selectedOption.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
    }
    
    $(element).trigger('chosen:updated');
  }
};

ko.applyBindings({
  getItemAvailableAccessTypes: function(data) {
    return [{
      codeForChosen: "Open",
      AccessTypeName: "Open access"
    }, {
      codeForChosen: "Restricted",
      AccessTypeName: "No access"
    }];
  },
  child: {
    AccessType: ko.observable("Restricted")
  }
});
```

```css
.chosen-container {
  width: 100% !important;
}
pre {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
  font: 11px consolas;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.5.1/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.5.1/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: child">
  <select data-bind="chosen: $parent.getItemAvailableAccessTypes($data), value: $data.AccessType,  optionsText: 'AccessTypeName',  optionsValue: 'codeForChosen'"></select>
</div>
<hr>Debug info: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for all, it work well. I hope there is no bug that I skip. I tried hard to understand your explaining about the solution, but not succeeded. If you can improve it- I will be happy. And, do you know why does this issue happen only with this version of knockout?

Comment: There are a lot of changes in the `options` bindings between those two versions... In 2.2.0 I can see `ko.utils.setOptionNodeSelectionState` being called every `update`, which doesn't seem to happen in 3.4.0... I might add some more explaining to my answer if I can find the time.